# Python Pandas Not Adding zero Values to Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I wrote a small python script to read from a CSV, check for certain values, then write results to another CSV file.

Here is my code
`

```
import pandas as pd
import os

current_directory = os.getcwd()
pf = pd.read_csv(current_directory + '\Appointments.csv')
total_kept = {}
for index, row in pf.iterrows():
    if total_kept.get(row['Acct#']) not in total_kept:
        values = {"row['Acct#']": 0}
        total_kept.update(values) //this line and the above one are supposed to initalize values to 0
        if row['Status'] == 'K':
            total_kept[row['Acct#']] = total_kept.get(row['Acct#'],0) + 1
    else:
        if row['Status'] == 'K':
            total_kept[row['Acct#']] = total_kept.get(row['Acct#'],0) + 1



with open("results.csv", 'w') as f:
    for key in total_kept.keys():
        f.write("%s, %s\n" % (key, total_kept[key]))
```

`

[image: Image of the source csv file]
[image: Image of the results]

For some reason, it is not adding ID's with no 'K' to the dictionary when they should have a value of 0. I am trying to count how many 'K' statuses from each ID. My thought was to create a dictionary with the key being the ID and the value being the number of 'K' instances.

Comment: Picture on left is starting CSV file. Right picture is the resulting CSV. Top value should be 1262, 0

Comment: It is not clear what you attempt to do, but `values = {"row['Acct#']": 0}` is incorrect.

Comment: That line is attempting to add a key with a value of zero if the key does not already exist.